# How to find eigenvectors of a matrix when the systems of equations have infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My goal is to find the eigenvectors of the matrix $A= \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

I have found the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-1$ and $\lambda_2=1$. Now, I’m trying to use the formula $(A-\lambda I_2)X= \vec0$ to find the eigenvectors.

For $\lambda_1=-1$, I found the following :

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1-(-1) & 0 \\ 2 & 1-(-1) \end{bmatrix} \times\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \times\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} 0x + 0y = 0 \\ 2x + 2y =0 \end{cases}$$

For $\lambda_2=1$, I found the following :

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1-(1) & 0 \\ 2 & 1-(1) \end{bmatrix} \times\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \times\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} -2x + 0y = 0 \\ 2x + 0y =0 \end{cases}$$

So, I find myself with 2 systems of equations with infinite solutions. What should I do in this situation to find the eigenvectors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your equations will infinitely many solutions. This is because eigenvectors span an *eigenspace*; if $a$ is an eigenvectors, then so are $2a,3a,4a,\cdots$.

You just need to pick an easy example for your eigenvectors, and then all multiples of them will still be eigenvectors. For the first system, you can extract the equation $y=-x$, which is spanned by the vector $(1,-1)^T$. For the second, $x=0$ and $y$ can be anything, so this is spanned by, say, the unit $y$ vector: $(0,1)^T$. You can go further and say that this line ($x=0$) is an invariant line of the matrix.

These are two possible choices of *representative* eigenvector; any choice will do!

An exercise/thought experiment for you would be to show that the set of eigenvectors, for a given eigenvalue of a matrix, really is a vector subspace (an eigenspace).

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response! I have two questions regarding your answer. Could you define T in the notation $(1,-1)^T$ ? And, for example, when you say that anything would work for $y$ in the second vector, does that mean $(0,24)$ works?

Comment: @Deskard Apologies for seeing this so late. Yes, $(0,24)$ works, as does any scalar multiple of it - try it! The $^T$ means transpose, so a row vector becomes a column vector, and I used this notation because it’s slightly more tedious to type out column vectors, and they take more formatting space: $$(1,-1)^T=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: No worries, thank you for your answer, it's all clear for me ! I didn't realize we could transpose a vector/matrix to write it like that, very cool, thanks again.

Comment: @Deskard You’re very welcome, and welcome to the stack